# NGINX server not executing php files

Tags: nginx, php

First at all I am new here and new to unix. My previous experience was solely with cPanel, Plesk etc. So please forgive me if there are some mistakes in my approach here.

I have a Centos (release 7.3.1611) VPS with Nginx (1.10.2) and PHP (7.0.17).

I followed some guides to get PHP running and followed some answers given here to similar problems as well to no avail.

Here is my configuration:

www.conf:

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

I changed permission and ownership on php-fpm.sock.

nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
```

nginx/default.d/default.conf:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name _;
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Finally I have created a info.php file. When executing it I am getting a nginx error: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

If disabling the nginx error page the browser is asking me if I want to download the file info.php.

Thank you for helping me out!!!

Comment: Do you get anything in the nginx error log when you see an error in the browser?

Comment: Did you restart the service after modifies to conf file? (sudo systemctl restart nginx)

Comment: Check the path to the Unix socket, and the permissions. If you have no luck with Unix sockets you can try with http ports. There will be hundreds of tutorials that tell you how to do that.

Comment: @USD Matt: There is nothing in the error logs

Comment: @lg.: Yes I did.

Comment: @Tim: Busy since two days with this issue. Studied dozens of guides, tried so many different approaches. Still no luck....

Comment: did you try to disable selinux?

Comment: Does your nginx user / group have permissions to read the php files you're trying to execute? Try using "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" in your PHP config and "fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000". The [official Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) is useful.

Comment: @Tim That was it! using "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" instead of "php-fpm.sock" sorted my problem. Thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use TCP sockets rather than Unix sockets. I find them easier to work with, and I've read they scale better.

In your PHP pool configuration (which for me is /etc/php-fpm-5.6.d/www.conf) change your listen to this line. Note that my

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

In your Nginx configuration use

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

A key thing is to ensure the users you define in your PHP pool have access to the files you want them to execute. Permissions are a major source of problems. You can test this by using sudo to assume their user.

```
sudo su nginx # or www-data, or whatever you use
cd /var/www/website
more filename.php
```

I have multiple websites using PHP, so I actually defined PHP in one conf file and then use it multiple times. So in upstream.conf I have

```
upstream php56-fpm {
  server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

fastcgi_pass php56-fpm;
```

I define multiple pools, to keep testing and production independent. My production pool always has listeners ready, my test pool doesn't. This is well explained [here](https://ma.ttias.be/a-better-way-to-run-php-fpm/).